# Gatsby not building but working fine in develop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, prismic.io

I'm creating a site using Gatysby and prismic. Everything seems to work fine in development. But when I try to build I get an "undefined" error.

```sh
Building static HTML failed for path "/preview/page"
```

```sh
  48 | const Page = (props) => {
  49 |  console.log(props);
> 50 |  const pageTitle = props.data.prismic.allPages.edges[0].node.page_title;
     |                                                         ^
  51 |  const content = props.data.prismic.allPages.edges[0].node.page_content;
  52 |  return (
  53 |          <>


  WebpackError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'node' of undefined
```

I'm not sure where the /preview/ is coming from because that is not the paths I have specified in the config file, and apparently previews are supposed to be disabled by default if I understand the documentation correctly - [documentation](https://prismic.io/docs/reactjs/getting-started/prismic-gatsby).

I tried setting them to false anyway but no luck.

This is my config atm

```js
        {
            resolve : 'gatsby-source-prismic-graphql',
            options : {
                repositoryName : 'XXXXX',
                pages          : [
                    {
                        type      : 'Page',
                        match     : '/:uid',
                        path      : '/',
                        component : require.resolve('./src/templates/page.js')
                    },
                    {
                        type      : 'Blog_post',
                        match     : '/blog/:uid',
                        path      : '/blog/',
                        component : require.resolve('./src/templates/blogPost.js')
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you need to add a validation check on your content. The documentation page you were looking at needs to be updated. I'll look into that.

By adding a validation check for content, the preview route can be generated without error. This page explains how to setup the validation check:
https://prismic.io/docs/gatsby/rendering/retrieve-the-document-object#21_0-adding-a-validation-check

Comment: Why is the preview route getting generated though? Since I haven't specified it in the config file it should be disabled right?

Comment: I think that the `options.pages.path` is for previews. The error might also go away if you remove that from the config, but I don't know that for sure.